# Can cypress CLI distinguish between an internal error and exactly one failing test?

Tags: cypress

From the `cypress run` docs:

"When Cypress finishes running tests, it exits. If there are no failed tests, the exit code will be 0. If there are any test failures, then the exit code will match the number of tests that failed. If Cypress could not run for some reason (for example if no spec files were found) then the exit code will be 1."

Because we want to retrieve the number of failed tests for use later in our Azure DevOps pipeline *and* also cause the pipeline to fail if cypress errors out for some internal reason, I'm using the following bash script:

```sh
      run_cypress () {
        node_modules/.bin/cypress run $(SpecFile) --browser chrome --headless
        case $? in
          1)
            return 1
            ;;
          0)
            # Set some pipeline variables
            return 0
            ;;
          *)
            NUM_TESTS=$?
            # Set some pipeline variables
            return 0
            ;;
        esac
      }
      run_cypress
```

We are now running into the entirely predictable corner case where we have a test suite that has exactly one failing test.  This is causing the whole pipeline to fail when it shouldn't.

Is there any way to reliably distinguish between "cypress has returned 1 because of a fatal error" and "cypress returned 1 because one test failed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the test results file exists, which should indicate that the test suite ran all the way through.

So, if the exit code is 1 and there are no results file present, consider it a fatal error.

```
npx cypress run --browser chrome
if [ $? -eq 1 ] &&  [ ! -f reports/result.json ]; then
  echo "Fatal error"
  exit 255;
fi
```